# Merging Data from Two Bindingsources

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I have Two `Binding sources` which are `preloaded with data from two database tables at the time Program loads(Main Form load)`.in a particular form,I want to use data from both tables,i mean data from both binding sources(even including duplicates).

**There is an alternative way ,using sql query to UNION both tables and binding it to the control.**

But it is not practical because the Query will return more than 150000 rows or more(slows down),that will ruin the performance of whole System.

so fellows,i am looking for some other way so that using the Preloaded data in both bindingsources here also.Please Suggest me Some good options.